# What is the reduced width amplitude of an unstable state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, scattering

Particularly used in nuclear physics when describing the lifetime (i.e. partial decay width) of a resonant state (a.k.a resonance) is the term "reduced width amplitude". I have searched online, and can't find any good explanations.

Could you explain what this is? (Or maybe provide a link to a good explanation?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question! I can maybe guide you in the right direction, although I only found this post because I wanted clarity myself.

The reduced width idea comes from the R-matrix formalism (a good paper is by Descouvemont and Baye [here](http://journals.aps.org/rmp/pdf/10.1103/RevModPhys.30.257)).

The most basic understanding of it is that the most general cross-section for an interaction of two nuclei (in which a compound nucleus is formed) is directly proportional to the square of the "R-matrix". The elements of an "R-matrix" are expressed by the equation
\begin{equation}
R_{cc'}(E) = \sum_{\lambda}\frac{\gamma_{\lambda c'}\gamma_{\lambda c}}{E_{\lambda}-E},
\end{equation}
where the $\gamma_{\lambda c'}$ and $\gamma_{\lambda c}$ are the "reduced width amplitudes" (which I think is the same as "reduced widths") for the incoming state c to form compound state $\lambda$ (the two nuclei undergo a collision and they fuse to make a compound state with some angular momentum) and the outgoing state c' (the compound nucleus decays to some (maybe different) pair).

The $E_{\lambda}$ is the energy of the state in the compound nucleus, and $E$ is the energy involved in the collision.

The picture you need in your head is two nuclides coming together under some interaction and forming a compound nucleus, which then after some time decays.

The reduced width amplitudes are related to the matrix element for the interaction between nuclides in pair c and state $\lambda$, and the nucleus in state $\lambda$ and a pair of particles (usually alpha-particles).

Comment: BTW - as an update: to extract the reduced width experimentally, all you need to do is divide 2$\pi\hbar$ by the lifetime of the state in question (or that's how it seems on pg. 169 of the book by Srivastava (https://books.google.co.za/books?id=g8oQj2qHFJYC&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=extract+reduced+widths+from+experiment+nuclear&source=bl&ots=v-Xvdwp0Pq&sig=iaVNqxQa1SkH6A3MGBHethMSApI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fNYSVeDSDYXwUNnmg8AF&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=extract%20reduced%20widths%20from%20experiment%20nuclear&f=false)). Best of luck with your calculations!